# "scroll-snap-type: y mandatory" has invisible margins in Safari

Tags: html, css, scroll, safari, scroll-snap

[Safari screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv16G.jpg)

So I have been trying to make sections stick to the top of the screen while scrolling.

I have used `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` for the `html` and `body` elements and `scroll-snap-align: start;` for the children (sections) elements.

This works as expected on Chrome (both Windows 10 and MacOS Big Sur) and Edge, but does not work correctly on Safari. On Safari the scroll goes a couple of hundred pixels too far, cropping the top of the desired sections and making the beginning of the next sections visible. The gap seems to grow bigger each section.
I have already tried:

```
scroll-padding-top: 0;
scroll-padding-bottom: 0;
```

on parents, and

```
scroll-snap-margin-top: 0;
scroll-snap-margin-bottom: 0;
```

on children.

None of the margin/padding values seem to improve the results (some of them go as far as making the gap bigger or breaking the scroll completely).

`scroll-snap-type: y proximity;` works as expected, but it is not the effect I am after.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is fixed in the newest Safari Technical Preview and iOS works fine too.

Page tested: https://fahrschule-bernhard.webflow.io/?

Comment: Now it's broken in Chrome though. Seems like it's going to take a while for this feature to work properly everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Using the -webkit prefix solved the problem to me while scrolling down.

On the parent (body and html)

```
-webkit-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
```

on children

```
-webkit-scroll-snap-align: start;
scroll-snap-align: start;
```

But no matter how far you've scrolled down, every time scrolling up is triggered it scrolls up to the top of the body, not as expected to the previous neighbour.

Comment: Seems like a Safari bug. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the project anymore to test it, but thank you anyway!